# Can we use Instagram API for Local Development

Tags: instagram

I am learning React Native by creating a clone of Instagram (Strictly Local Development). I want to use the Instagram API to get some real time data for my app. I tried registering as Instagram Developer but its asking me for the website and policy page of the website, which I don't have. Is it possible to use Instagram API for learning purpose, if so can you give me the steps for ding it??

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. I think you're already in the right way. All you need to do is just integrate things up and follow all the steps in the Instagram Developer website.

You are not required to have policy page or anything to use the sandbox, but you will need it later on if you want to use the API in the production state of your app.

You will need to create an app in the developer site, and generate your access token. Then, add a sandbox user (your Instagram account) and start to use the User Endpoint to retrieve your user data (such as your bio, follower count, etc.) and media (this is what you want, your Instagram post feed).

Hope this helps.